# Error installing PHP7.1 with apache2 on debian 9

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php

Hello I installed the apache with debian's 9 installation. Then installed php7.0 with apt-get but I need to install php7.1, at first I do

```
# su
# apt-get purge php7.0
```

so I downloaded from http://php.net/downloads.php php 7.1.10 and make this

```
# ./configure --with-mcrypt
# make
# make install
```

but `phpinfo()` get the php7.0, so I make

```
# su
# apt-get purge php7.0 
# apt-get autoremove php7.0
```

and know `phpinfo()` is not working. I sumed that now php is not installed.

Then downloaded from http://php.net/downloads.php php 7.1.11 (new today) and inside

```
# tar jxvf php-7.1.11.tar.bz2
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get install libxml2-dev libmcrypt-dev libjpeg-dev
# cd php-7.1.11
# ./configure --with-mcrypt --with-pdo-pgsql=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-zlib --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

And between all the checks I get the next errors

```
Configuring SAPI modules
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS... [Fri Oct 27 12:30:45.328686 2017] [core:warn] [pid 12056] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
yes

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Sury repo for this (https://deb.sury.org/), this is a small script to add it to your repo list.

```
#!/bin/bash
# To add this repository please do:

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    SUDO=sudo
fi

${SUDO} apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
${SUDO} wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
${SUDO} sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
${SUDO} apt-get update
```

- Source: https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

It is far a better option to use Debian repo to install SW rather than to go manual, it will avoid you a lot of headaches :)

Comment: I got one more question, with phpinfo() I get PHP Version 7.1.11-1 and inside terminal I get 7.1.10. How can I change that? and I get this error in terminal The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available

Comment: I created a new question for this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401421/problem-with-2-php-version-and-openssl

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing SSL dev. Try this...

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Likely this will solve your problem.

Tip: Anytime you're missing a file, use apt-get to find it's package...

```
apt-file search /evp.h | egrep '/evp.h$'
```

Comment: I've installed libssl-dev: $ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

Comment: Post an update as to whether this fixed your problem or your problem persists or if you have a new problem.

Comment: I marked this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401405/245622 as the answer