# Problem with 2 php version and openssl

Tags: apache-httpd, php, openssl

Hello I got 2 errors I don't know how to solve.

First: installed manually the php7.1.10 and the installed by apt-get the version 7.1.11 (following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401405/245622) steps). Know with a phpinfo() I get PHP Version 7.1.11-1 but inside terminal I get 7.1.10. How can I change the cli inside terminal so I get the same version?

Second: I'm getting this error `The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available.` making a `php composer.phar install`. Inside the phpinfo I get `OPENSSL support enabled` but inside terminal I get `OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)`. So maybe this could be solved by changing the php version that i'm using inside terminal.

enviroment: debian9, apache 2.4

Any help? thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post the output of `type php`?

Comment: php is /usr/local/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this

```
# type php
php is /usr/local/bin/php
# cd /usr/local/bin/php
# sudo mv php phpbak
# type php
php is /usr/bin/php
# php -v
PHP 7.1.11-1
```

Comment: You're asking for a world of pain down the road. _shrug_

Answer (score 0):

Use alternatives for this, this way you can control and move between versions and configs as needed: 
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives

Once configured the change is as easy as:

`sudo update-alternatives --set php ${path to PHP executable}`